# mysqldump piped to gzip then s3 doesn't to run out of disk space

Tags: mysqldump

I run the following command which all.sql.gz is greater than the amount of free space on hard drive....but somehow it completes without issue. Is it because of how the piping works?

```
mysqldump --defaults-file=/home/ec2-user/db-master.cnf --tz-utc=false --quick --all-databases --single-transaction --routines --triggers | gzip | s3cmd "$BACKUP_OPTIONS" put - "$BACKUP_S3PATH"/"php-pos-db"/"all".sql.gz >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your command that would result in any data being written to your hard drive at all. It's not surprising that it would not use any hard drive space, because it does not use any hard drive space.

Comment: Wouldn't it need a place to store the data or does it use memory?

Comment: It looks like you're just sending the data to S3. All the commands in your pipeline are just operating in memory.